# mapping '2' key in Thai resulting in '/'

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I copied the code from [vim-thai-keys](https://github.com/chakrit/vim-thai-keys/blob/master/plugin/vim-thai-keys.vim) to my `.vimrc` file and made a few adjustments.

**My problem:** Typing the '2' key while using the Thai keyboard in Normal mode either sends me to `/search` mode or moves the cursor two spaces to the right and I am thus unable to use 2 in a keystroke navigation or editing combination.

**Note:** The symbol on the Thai keyboard corresponding to the English key '2' is '/'.

Changes made to .vimrc file and the results of typing '2' from the Thai keyboard while in Normal mode.

1. `:map / 2` — *Result: Cursor moves 2 spaces to the right*
2. `:map \/ 2` — *Result: Sent into `/search` mode*
3. `nnoremap / 2` — *Result: Cursor moves 2 spaces to the right*
4. `nnoremap \/ /` — *Result: Sent into `/search` mode*

   All of the other numbers and key stroke mappings seem to work wonderfully.

*(Yes, I restarted vim after editing the .vimrc file) :) :)*

**Question:** Is there a way to map the '2' key so that while in the Thai keyboard in Normal mode I am able to use it as a normal 2 in navigation and editing keystroke combinations?

**Bonus points:** Should I use `:map` or `nnoremap` in my `.vimrc` file for these key stroke mappings and why.

Comment: You might have an extra space character after the `nnoremap / 2`. If so, you're basically moving 2 spaces to the right, since `:h <Space>` states that it is equivalent to `l` (move "`[count]` chars to the right"). Alway use the `*noremap` form, unless you know you need recursive mappings.

Comment: Yes indeed. There was a space after the 2.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the `<Leader>` key which I have chosen to map to `<space>`.

```
map <space> <Leader>
nnoremap <Leader>/ 2
```

Make sure there are no spaces after the 2.

Another useful mapping for Thai is:

```
nnoremap <Leader>ไ W
```

This resolves the conflict on the Thai keyboard with the `"` key while removing the need to include the `<shift>` key.